# how to resolt prblem adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (40)?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, adb, version

content error of me below

i comflic between both adb version

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\User>adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
Version 28.0.2-5303910
Installed as C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

C:\Users\User>cd C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.5-6877874
Installed as C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear in which case it happens.

But base on the information that you provide..

It looks like you have a few android SDK, In rare and specific cases, you need to keep them e.g. if you use some custom SDK.

But in general, you have to keep only one, I suggest you delete one of them and of course, don't forget to change your environment variables and SDK paths in your IDE's settings.

P.S. *I think that it has to be in the comments but I don't have enough reputation for it*